# mysql get second possible value when first one is not available

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

In my application, I have list of freelancers in a table and their working rates configuration in another table. Working rates configuration is like Per Hr rate, Per Day Rate, Per Work Type rate

Some freelancers do not have per hr rate, instead Per day or Per Work Type.

My initial query is (LEFT OUTER) joining freelancer table with freelancer_workrates table and filtering the rows based on perhrrate. Whenever a perhrrate is not available, then I would like to retrieve their next available rate using the same query. Is that possible?

Currently, I checking this in resultset and making a separate call for those freelancers to get their next available rate. This ends up in making too many SQL queries to database. I would like to avoid this situation.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function?

Comment: And if the `IFNULL()` and `COALESCE()` function don't help your situation (no example query provided means we can't provide an actual solution, only advice) you could try `UNION` to piece together otherwise separate queries into one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce`

This will pick first non NULL value out of three rates

```
  Coalesce(perHrRate, perDayRate, perWorkTypeRate)
```